# GetFolderFromPathAsync function access denied

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm making a Windows 10 Universal App and I want the user to pick a folder to save the document files for the App. The path for this folder is saved to `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values`.
Here's the code:

On first Start:

```
var folderPicker = new FolderPicker { SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder };
        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        StorageFolder homeFolder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync("App1 Data", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        var save = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values;
        save["HomeFolder"] = homeFolder.Path;
```

When HomeFolder is set:

```
string dir = save["HomeFolder"].ToString();
        try
        {
            StorageFolder homeFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(dir);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

The thrown Exception in the second code sample is:

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: access denied (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

So my question is, how do you use the GetFolderFromPathAsync function correctly?
I checked all strings for the paths, they are all right, even

`StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(storageFolder.Path);`

doesn't work.
Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the StorageFile directly rather than converting to a path.

To store the file returned from the file picker for later use save the StorageFile in the AccessCache classes FutureAccessList or MostRecentlyUsedList. The path doesn't include the spermissions needed to open the file. The StorageFile carries the permissions and grants access to the file.

I discussed this in more detail in my blog entry [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/12/05/stray-from-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile.aspx)

Comment: Will I be ablle to get items of this FutureAccessList after restarting the App?

Comment: Yes, that's sort of the point. If it worked only within a single run of the app, then you wouldn't need the FutureAccessList in the first place; you would just keep using the StorageFile.

Comment: Hello Rob, I've read your blog post and I've mixed feelings about this - I understand the reason of such approach, the privileges and so on. But what in case I need to store a location of more than 1000 files? Lets assume that I've an app that shows pictures on the phone, some kind of database and I need to have access to files selected by user, I don't want to limit user to 1000 files. Is it safe to use path approach for files returned from PicturesLibrary which reside on phone? What's the best practice for a database with large amount of files?

Comment: Worse still, each StorageFile or StorageFolder that you hold seems to cause RuntimeBroker.exe to allocate about 60k. No sign of Microsoft doing anything about this.