# StorageFolder "access denied"

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core, storagefolder

My problem is i want to save a picture on a network path

i have tried this:

```
private async void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\myserver\signatures");

     StorageFile file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("InkSample.jpg");
}
```

But I get an error : Access denied. How can i fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetFolderFromPathAsync function access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200332/getfolderfrompathasync-function-access-denied)

Comment: If you are running this locally then it is your account that does not have access. If this is deployed to a server, then its the account that your web site runs under that doesn't have access. Do a simple test and see if you can access a folder on your machine.

Comment: @Wheels73, i try to use a domain user to start Visual Studio and to run the app-debugg but always same error with access denied. I see if my user has rights on the shared folder and he has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"access denied" may be caused by missing some capabilities:

- The home and work networks capability:  PrivateNetworkClientServer
- And at least one internet and public networks capability: InternetClient, InternetClientServer
- And, if applicable, the domain credentials capability: EnterpriseAuthentication
- Note: You must add File Type Associations to your app manifest that declare specific file types that your app can access in this location.

Ref: "[file access permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)"

After adding these capabilities, UWP app works on desktop but not working for me on Windows IoT Core device. And I get the following error:

> "Cannot access the specified file or folder. The item is not in a location that the application has access to (including application data folders, folders that are accessible via capabilities, and persisted items in the StorageApplicationPermissions lists). Verify that the file is not marked with system or hidden file attributes."

Comment: Thanks Rita Han, I add File Type Associations to my app manifest and that solve my problem. Thanks all for your help. See you

Comment: I am glad to help.

Comment: @cretgil Hi cretgil, if the answer solved your issue you can [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so we can close this thread and help others searching on this topic.